# Inputting correct answer gives incorrect output. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a game where the user needs to answer math questions to beat a monster. I haven't added code for that yet but my current issue is that when I input the **correct** answer to a math question it says that it's wrong. Even though they are both integers, it's still not right.

I just edited the code so that it can be tested.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import random   


class Easy(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        def question(self):
            self.listAnswer = []
            self.listUserAnswer = []
            intOne = random.randrange(1,10)
            intTwo = random.randrange(1,10)
            self.listAnswer.append(intOne + intTwo)
            self.strQuestion = "{} + {}".format(intOne, intTwo)
```

This is where it says that the answer inputted was incorrect.

```
        def attack(self):
            self.intUserAnswer = self.a_entry.get()
            self.listUserAnswer.append(self.intUserAnswer)
            if self.listUserAnswer[self.i] == self.listAnswer[self.i]:
                print("yes")
                self.i += 1
            else:
                print("no")
                print(self.listUserAnswer[self.i])
                print(self.listAnswer[self.i])

        def func():
            attack(self)
            self.a_entry.delete(0,END)

        def game(self):
            self.i = 0
            question(self)
            q_label = Label(self, text=self.strQuestion)
            q_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.70, anchor='center')

            self.a_entry = Entry(self, width=5, font=("Helvetica", 20, "bold"))
            self.a_entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.80, anchor='center')

            attack_button = Button(self, bg="blue", text="ATTACK!", command=func)
            attack_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.90, anchor='center')

        game(self)            

root = tk.Tk()
Easy(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.title("Battle Maths")
root.geometry("400x250")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue but its solution is quite simple. The problem is located in your attack() function. Precisely here: `self.intUserAnswer = self.a_entry.get()`. At this point, you made the wrong assumption that you are getting the user input from the `tkinter.Entry()` widget you called `self.a_entry`. Actually all what you are getting in `attack()` function is None.

Your code is incomplete, ideally you should provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can give you a precise solution, however without it I believe you can just associate  callback method to an event (button press, most probably) thanks to which you retrieve the value typed by the user in `self.a_entry` widget, then you can forward it to your `attack()` function.

Comment: Ok but I do not see any widgets in your code when I run it.

Comment: I don't understand why you claim `self.a_entry.get()` is returning `None`.

Comment: Just fixed it actually, used `int(UserAnswer)`.